# answers without questions

Tags: feature-request

Somewhere, I read "document your struggles". Sometimes, I want to ask a question just to share the answer that I found myself. What if we could share tutorials and have them voted for usefulness?

Comment: Da-da-da-DA Da-da-da, Da-da-da-da-DUM-da-dada-dada...

Comment: The above is, of course, my scoffworthy transcription of muttering the Jeopardy theme music.

Comment: +1  I think that's a great idea.  People could search the tutorials before asking an already answered question.

Comment: But puhleeze, mark the answer right away.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. One of the dupes is even an [official FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with asking a question so that you can answer it. From [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask. It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.